# Forward subdomain link to domain with same path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want to forward all external links for my site that start with a subdomain, to the same path, but without the subdomain.

Ex. :
`https://mail.example.org/path1/file`

To be:
`https://example.org/path1/file`

I tried adding the following to .htaccess but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I aslo tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [L,P]` but didn't work.

Comment: Could you please confirm once if vhosts are created from your side?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for the reply.  I am not sure what you mean, but yes, I have access to `/etc/apache2` if that what you mean.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, what I meant was just wanted to be clear that your sub domain is created and present, because your rules are looking fine to me.

Comment: The actual subdomain I want to forward called "mail" and I have it in the DNS records page under type "**A**".

Comment: Your explanation and the examples don’t really match. With `mail.example.org`, `mail` would be a “subdomain” of `example.org` here, in common lingo. `mail.org` is not a subdomain of `example.org`.

Comment: @CBroe Right, sorry, fixed.  It should redirect to `https://example.org/path1/file`.

Comment: _“The actual subdomain I want to forward called "mail" and I have it in the DNS records page under type "A".”_ - that so far only means, that clients will resolve that host name to your server’s IP address. It does not mean, that your server already knows what to do with requests for that host name. If you do not have a virtual host set up that routes this host name into the specific directory your .htaccess is in, it will likely go into whatever the default Vhost is.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wildcard subdomain for your domain, and add a virtualhost for it, if there is not a virtual host without `ServerName`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /path/to/an/example/documentroot
#make sure mod_rewrite is enabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

This will forward all subdomains without a separate VirtualHost.